# Custom axis formatting (mixed numbers and strings) in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

See picture below:

is it possible to define such axis formatting, that instead of showing negative values (e.g. -20), it would display some text like 'undefined'?

[image: X Axis]

Comment: You can use [`axis.tickFormat()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) for that.

Comment: Could not replace the values with stings with axis.tickFormat(). I managed to remove all negative ticks, but i am still wondering if i could replace them with a custom string.

Comment: You can return anything you like in the function you pass to `.tickFormat`, including a custom string.

Answer (score 0):

As Lars mentions, it's the axis.tickFormat() method that you need. Use it like this:

```
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
        if(d >= 0){
          return d;} else {
          return 'Undefined';}
    });
```